# Image Conversions in Android?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, jpeg

> I want to build an app which converts image formats. I was trying
>   convert an JPG image to BMP, while doing so i get OOM, cause app
>   memory is limited that its unable to use the array to store the image
>   for conversion. If this is the case, how there are apps which does the
>   same??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the actual conversion has to look like, but in every case you will need a buffer or something like that, to consume the jpg. Because Android memory heap is between 24-48mb (one memory block) you run out of memory while trying to convert.

Answer (score 0):

Memory of Android app is limited. The amount of available memory varies by device. So editing big images on an older device might be really a problem.

Solution to this is to use NDK. In NDK you can allocated much more memory than Java apps could have.

Comment: i know the app memory is limited..........and i have a c code which converts an jpeg to bmp using libjpeg.so through google. I am trying use it in ndk already but still haven't found a way. Any cue on this??

Comment: And Google recommends NDK not that much, it says you use it only when you have no option. So the present in play store how they do that? Games uses lot of memory, how they are confined with the limited space?

Comment: Well, I don't know libjpeg and how it handles memory. But if you want to go outside VM memory limits (16-48 MB) you have to use NDK, where you can malloc much more memory (easily > 100 MB). You can basically allocate as much memory as you want. It's true that most apps don't need NDK. But one of the exceptions are games, most of them are written in NDK.

Comment: Where did you find the libjpeg.so? You may need to have a small stub .cpp program to pass the .jpg to, then have the stub send the image to the library to convert, then pass the converted file back to the java.

Comment: there is a jpeg source in android source....i took the source, built it in ndk and got the .so......using that in the image conversion app, i get only undefined ref....for the apis present in .so